# PHP removing backslash from code submitted through $_POST

Tags: php

I have a code editor block and and submitting code like the following:

```
$something = "<a href=\"somepage.html\">Link</a>";
```

However, when I submit it the string that gets output is missing the backslash escape characters and I get:

```
$something = "<a href="somepage.html">Link</a>";
```

...which obviously isn't correct. I've figured out that it has to do with magic_quotes_gpc and when turned "On" works properly. My goal is for the application to be able to be installed easily on multiple hosts and I'd like to avoid having to turn on magic_quotes_gpc on every instance.

Comment: Can't you use signle quotes? `$something = '<a href="somepage.html">Link</a>';`

Comment: a) `magic_quotes_gpc` is an abomination and it's completely unacceptable for your app to use it (let alone require it). b) Where do you *submit* the string and how does it *get output*? There's someone in that pipeline that strips the slashes from the input. Find and fix the root cause instead of randomly adding `addslashes` as some suggest. c) The reason magic quotes "solves" the problem is that it adds *more* slashes, which are then stripped by the unknown culprit, leaving you with the original text.

Answer (score 0):

[Link Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php#103630)

> Magic Quotes are depreciated and going
>   to be removed in PHP6. If you still
>   want your code to be portable, no
>   warnings etc, as of PHP52 you can use
>   the following code.

```
<?php
    foreach ($_GET as $key => &$val)
        $val = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $key);

    foreach ($_POST as $key => &$val)
        $val = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $key);
?>
```

> The above will retrieve an-escaped
>   GETs and POSTs regardless system
>   settings. It can also be used for
>   $_COOKIES and others.

Comment: Magic quotes were already [removed in PHP 5.4.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try double escaping:

`$something = "<a href=\\"somepage.html\\">Link</a>";`

Answer (score 0):

The [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)-method might be what you're looking for.

However, if you want to directly put those values in a Database, you can use the [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)-method or you go with a [Prepared Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).